# Difference between ArrayList and LinkedList in Java - the whys for performance

Tags: java, performance, collections, arraylist, linked-list

I thought I understood the difference between ArrayList and LinkedList theoretically pretty well. However, its the first time, I put it to a little test, and the tests came out, well different to my expectations.

Expectations :

1. Arraylist will be slower than LinkedList when inserting at the
   beginning, since it has to "shift" the elements, for linkedlist, its
   just updating 2 references.

   Reality : came out to be same on most iterations. For a select few
   iterations, it was slower.
2. Arraylist will be slower than LinkedList when deleting at the beginning, since it has to "shift" the elements, for Linkedlist, its just nullifying one element.

   Reality : Performance was same when deleting from beg.

Test Case : 1,000,000 elements

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1000000;

    List arrayList = new ArrayList(n+10);
    long milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i= 0 ;i<n;i++){
        arrayList.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println("insert arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    List linkedList = new LinkedList();
    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i= 0 ;i<n;i++){
        linkedList.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println("insert linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    //System.out.println("Adding at end");
    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.add(n-5,n+1);
    System.out.println("APPEND arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.add(n-5,n+1);
    System.out.println("APPEND linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    //add at front
    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.add(0,0);
    System.out.println("INSERT BEG arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.add(0,0);
    System.out.println("INSERT BEG linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    //add at middle
    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.add(n/2,n/2);
    System.out.println("INSERT MIDDLE arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.add(n/2,n/2);
    System.out.println("INSERT MIDDLE linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    //get from front, mid, end
    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.get(0);
    System.out.println("get front arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.get(0);
    System.out.println("get front linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.get(n/2);
    System.out.println("get MIDDLE arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.get(n/2);
    System.out.println("get MIDDLE linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.get(n-4);
    System.out.println("get last arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.get(n-4);
    System.out.println("get last linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    //delete from front, mid, end.
    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.remove(0);
    System.out.println("del front arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.remove(0);
    System.out.println("del front linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.remove(n/2);
    System.out.println("del mid arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.remove(n/2);
    System.out.println("del mid linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    arrayList.remove(n-4);
    System.out.println("del end arraylist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

    milis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    linkedList.remove(n-4);
    System.out.println("del end linkedlist takes "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-milis)+" ms");

}
```

**Output Log**

```
insert arraylist takes 141 ms
insert linkedlist takes 312 ms
APPEND arraylist takes 0 ms
APPEND linkedlist takes 0 ms
INSERT BEG arraylist takes 0 ms
INSERT BEG linkedlist takes 0 ms
INSERT MIDDLE arraylist takes 0 ms
INSERT MIDDLE linkedlist takes 0 ms
get front arraylist takes 0 ms
get front linkedlist takes 0 ms
get MIDDLE arraylist takes 0 ms
get MIDDLE linkedlist takes 16 ms
get last arraylist takes 0 ms
get last linkedlist takes 0 ms
del front arraylist takes 0 ms
del front linkedlist takes 0 ms
del mid arraylist takes 0 ms
del mid linkedlist takes 15 ms
del end arraylist takes 0 ms
del end linkedlist takes 0 ms
```

So what's the reason? JDK 1.6 used.

EDIT : After using System.nanotime(), it did give me answers as I expected. Agreed, its only a single trial, and should be averaged.

```
insert arraylist takes 137076082 ns
insert linkdlist takes 318985917 ns
APPEND arraylist takes 69751 ns
APPEND linkdlist takes 98126 ns
**INSERT BEG arraylist takes 2027764 ns
INSERT BEG linkdlist takes 53522 ns**
INSERT MIDDLE arraylist takes 1008253 ns
INSERT MIDDLE linkdlist takes 10395846 ns
get front arraylist takes 42364 ns
get front linkdlist takes 77473 ns
get MIDDLE arraylist takes 39499 ns
get MIDDLE linkdlist takes 9645996 ns
get last arraylist takes 46165 ns
get last linkdlist takes 43446 ns
**del front arraylist takes 1720329 ns
del front linkdlist takes 108063 ns**
del mid arraylist takes 1157398 ns
del mid linkdlist takes 11845077 ns
del end arraylist takes 54149 ns
del end linkdlist takes 49744 ns
```

Comment: when performing micro benchmarking, always use `System.nanoTime()`

Comment: I wonder how much time autoboxing of int takes in your case, on your first pass you will be filling Integers cache

Comment: Agree with @Nishant above. The 0ms for most tests is not helpful. The real time might be say 50nanoseconds vs 300nanoseconds.

Comment: Dont do single tests, do average like you do on your first test

Comment: Yes, thanks Nishant, my mistake. Reverting to nanos, justifies the expectations.

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed in that you perform multiple tests in the same JVM invocation. Later tests may have the benefit of the JVM being warmed up (JIT, etc) by previous tests. You should run each test in its own JVM invocation.

Comment: @SteveKuo, thank you. Yes, I thought so.That is why I used only the 1st invokation every time. Subsequent immediate invokations proved "almost" equivalent for both linkedlist and arraylist. But that brings another question to my mind, many have opined that the benchmnarks should be averaged, which I agree to, but shouldn't the subsequent test cases(on the same JVM invokation) fall under the same trap of probably averaging out the best cases?

Comment: [A better comparison is available here](http://www.javabeat.net/difference-arraylist-vector-linkedlist-java/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation for your first two (weird) test numbers is:

Inserting into ArrayList is generally slower because it has to grow once you hit its boundaries. It will have to create a new bigger array, and copy data from the original one.

But when you create an ArrayList that is *already huge* enough to fit all your inserts (which is your case since you're doing `new ArrayList(n+10)`) - it will obviously not involve any array copying operations. Adding to it will be even faster than with LinkedList because LinkedList will have to deal with its "links" (pointers), while huge ArrayList just sets value at given (last) index.

Also your tests are not good because each iteration involves autoboxing (conversion from int to Integer) - it will both take additional time to do that and will also screw up the results because of the [Integers cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307904/autoboxing-vs-manual-boxing-java) that will get filled on the first pass.

Answer (score 2):

`int n = 1000000;` is too small. You get `0 ms` doesn't really mean that it takes no time to complete the insertion or deletion. It means that the time elapsed is less than 1ms . Try rising the number of `int n = 1000000;` . You can see the difference then.

EDIT: I have misread your code. I thought that you are inserting `n` elements in the front of the array list. You should definitely insert multiple items instead of inserting one only.

ANOTHER EDIT: If you insert `n` elements, you would not need to raise the value of `n`. Conversely, you would probably want to decrease it because inserting in the front of ArrayList is a slow operation.

Comment: @KarthikT Oh yes. I realised that right before you post the comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With an ArrayList, the insert at the middle operation is going to be two steps in terms of theoretical Big Oh:

- O(1) to find the position and insert the new value
- O(n) to shift the remaining values forward.

With a LinkedList, if the relevant Node is not known yet (looping from the head node), it is also two steps:

- O(n) to find the Node at the position
- O(1) to insert the new value

However, besides the expected algorithmic complexity, there are other points that can have an impact on the actual runtime:

- Specific language implementations might make parts of a specific process faster. In this case, Java's arraycopy(), which ArrayList uses, seams faster than a for-loop copying each value. This might not be true for all arrays (sizes, types) -  again, it will be implementation specific.
- Big Oh ignores constants that might have an impact on certain datasets. For example, Bubble Sort is O(n*n) but can detect a pre-sorted array in O(n) and is very fast with almost-sorted arrays.
- LinkedList requires more memory to be requested to the virtual machine (creation of the Node object). Processes that require more memory to be requested can sometimes be causes for bottlenecks.

To summarize: beware of theoretical assumptions and always measure, preferably with real world data and operations :).